# Admob interstitial orientation

Tags: android, admob, screen-orientation

I want to present admob interstitial ad in certain orientation in my ad depending on config i get from my server

Before i present the ad i set the activity orientation like this (for example if i want landscape):

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    if ((VeediUtils.gamePreferences.getOrientation() != null)) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        newConfig.orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 17) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
    };
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

In the manifest i have this attribute which says that i handle orientation change:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|smallestScreenSize|screenSize"
```

The problem is that admob ad is still showing in portrait the orientation dont change to landscape

Answer (score 1):

`onConfigurationChanged` is a callback to notify you that the configuration has changed. It is not a means of changing the screen orientation.

You would need to change your screen orientation elsewhere, probably before you display the interstitial ad.

NB changing the screen orientation like this will be a very frustrating and annoying UX. I would recommend against it.